# Why are there two SDK packages for .NET Core 2.2 on MS website?

Tags: .net-core, sdk

The website [dotnet.microsoft.com](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) is, as of today, offering two versions of SDKs for .NET Core 2.2. One has a small text next to it "(compatible with VS2017)".

Can someone please explain why is the other one NOT compatible, or why does this separation exist in the first place? How are they different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was covered on the latest (at the time of writing) [ASP.NET Community Standup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t79ol1jzK1s). I would recommend watching that (and each of the standups, as they are done live and viewers can submit questions to be answered).

Essentially, both are slightly separate builds of the SDK. Hovering on the boxes at the site (as shown in the following image), shows that the URLs for the SDKs which are linked to are different.

[image: showing the two SDK boxes available on the .NET Core download website]

The first link downloads version 2.2.204 of the SDK, whereas the second link downloads 2.2.107 of the SDK.

This is because there are known issues with 2.2.204 and Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio for Mac. This is partially due to how VS 2019 looks for installations of the SDK, which should be fixed in version 3.

If you are going to do all development from the CLI or with Visual Studio 2019 install the 2.2.204 version. If not (i.e. you are using VS 2017 or VS for Mac), install 2.2.107.